# Como evitar que o HttpPost do ADVPL imprima o payload no arquivo de log?

Tags: advpl

Estou fazendo uma rotina de envio de informações do Protheus para o meu sistema. Para enviar as informações, estou usando a função [`HttpPost`](http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/HTTPPost), e envio um pacote de dados de atualização. Cada requisição envia, só de payload, algo em torno de 190KiB.

Para enviar todos os dados os quais necessito, são necessários diversos envios (por volta de 2000 requisições). Notei que, para cada um desses envios, está sendo impresso no arquivo de log toda a requisição (incluindo método, URL, *headers* e *payload*).

Tem como evitar essa escrita no arquivo de log? Na documentação da função não tem nenhuma informação disponível sobre isso, inclusive foi-me uma surpresa ver isso. Não gostaria de escrever mais de 300 MiB no log desnecessariamente.

---

Esses logs citados anteriormente foram encontrados nos arquivos `console_KVP4XK_PRD_COMP_11001.log` e `console_kvp4xk_prd_comp_11001.bak`. Abaixo retirei dois excertos que creio serem representativos.

No programa que estava rodando, tinha a chamada da `CONOUT` para simplesmente exibir o resultado da chamada `HttpPost`, indicando qual foi a string retornada pelo meu serviço (ou, caso não retorne nada, escrever "**Resultado nulo**"). Percebi agora que a requisição só é impressa no caso em que meu servidor retorna sucesso.

Abaixo o código da função `SENDJS` num estado muito próximo ao que foi usada no segundo excerto:

```
static function sendJs(cUrl, cPostPar, nTimeOut, aHeaderStr, aResponse)
    Local cMsgHttp  := "[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: "
    Local cResponse
    Local cHeaderRet

    If cPostPar <> "INATIVO"
        cResponse := HttpPost( cUrl, "", cPostPar, nTimeOut, aHeaderStr, @cHeaderRet)

        If cResponse == nil
            cResponse := "Resultado nulo"
        EndIf

        conout(cMsgHttp + cResponse)
    Else
        cResponse := "INATIVO"
    EndIf
    aadd(aResponse, cResponse)
Return cResponse
```

Sem nenhum `CONOUT` a mais.

Um excerto que creio ser significativo do log:

```
POST /my/exemplo/end-point HTTP/1.1

Host: my.example.http.host:8080

HEADER_PVT: PVT_VALUE

Content-type: application/json

Content-Length: 195145



{"cliente":[{"cd_cliente":"YYYY","nm_cliente":"NOME NOME NOME","nm_fantasia":"NOME NOME NOME",...resto do payload
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: OK
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo

POST /my/exemplo/end-point HTTP/1.1

Host: my.example.http.host:8080

HEADER_PVT: PVT_VALUE

Content-type: application/json

Content-Length: 194517



{"cliente":[{"cd_cliente":"ZZZZ","nm_cliente":"NOME NOME NOME","nm_fantasia":"NOME NOME NOME",...resto do payload
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: OK
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo

/*-------------------------------------------------------
THREAD ERROR ([9540], ####, #####)   20/11/2018   11:44:00
Remote Connection BROKEN on RETFILENAME(APLIB070.PRW) 28/05/2018 10:29:39 line : 542

[build: 7.00.131227A-20180425]
[environment: KVP4XK_PRD_COMP]
[thread: 9540]
[dbthread: 4916]
[rpodb: Top]
[localfiles: CTREE]
[remark: |Emp :02/02020099 Logged :             SIGAFAT Obj :WFPrepEnv]
[stack: 42448 bytes]
[memory: 28345912 bytes]
[peak memory: 28534528 bytes]
[threadtype: RmtSockThread]
Called from MSFILE(APLIB070.PRW) 28/05/2018 10:29:39 line : 173
Called from CHKFILE(APLIB200.PRW) 23/05/2017 15:25:06 line : 915
Called from XCHKFILE(APLIB240.PRW) 18/08/2017 17:44:03 line : 405
Called from RTERRHANDLER(APLIB240.PRW) 18/08/2017 17:44:03 line : 342
Called from { |E| RTERRHANDLER(E) } line : 1
Called from LINHAJSON(SGEOF001.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45
Called from U_MAKEALLJSON(SGEOF001.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45 line : 302
Called from U_ENVJSONAPLIC(SGEOF003.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45 line : 74
Called from U_EXECATU(SGEOF004.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45 line : 93
Called from U_SGEOJ001(SGEOJ001.PRW) 12/11/2018 11:06:43 line : 35

 Stack : 
Remote Connection BROKEN on RETFILENAME(APLIB070.PRW) 28/05/2018 10:29:39 line : 542

[build: 7.00.131227A-20180425]
[environment: KVP4XK_PRD_COMP]
[thread: 9540]
[dbthread: 4916]
[rpodb: Top]
[localfiles: CTREE]
[remark: |Emp :02/02020099 Logged :             SIGAFAT Obj :WFPrepEnv]
[stack: 42448 bytes]
[memory: 28345912 bytes]
[peak memory: 28534528 bytes]
[threadtype: RmtSockThread]
Called from MSFILE(APLIB070.PRW) 28/05/2018 10:29:39 line : 173
Called from CHKFILE(APLIB200.PRW) 23/05/2017 15:25:06 line : 915
Called from XCHKFILE(APLIB240.PRW) 18/08/2017 17:44:03 line : 405
Called from RTERRHANDLER(APLIB240.PRW) 18/08/2017 17:44:03 line : 342
Called from { |E| RTERRHANDLER(E) } line : 1
Called from LINHAJSON(SGEOF001.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45
Called from U_MAKEALLJSON(SGEOF001.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45 line : 302
Called from U_ENVJSONAPLIC(SGEOF003.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45 line : 74
Called from U_EXECATU(SGEOF004.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45 line : 93
Called from U_SGEOJ001(SGEOJ001.PRW) 12/11/2018 11:06:43 line : 35
-------------------------------------------------------*/

[INFO ][SERVER] [Thread 9540] [20/11/2018 11:44:00] Thread finished (####, #####, 27.21 MB.) 

[INFO ][SERVER] Cleaning 1 Global Variable Value(s).

[INFO ][SERVER] [Thread 9596] [21/11/2018 11:27:27] Starting Debugger (####, #####)

[INFO ][SERVER] [Thread 9596] [21/11/2018 11:27:32] Debugger finished (####, #####)

[INFO ][SERVER] [Thread 16636] [21/11/2018 11:27:41] Starting Debugger (####, #####)

[INFO ][SERVER] [Thread 16636] Env [KVP4XK_PRD_COMP] DBAccess Connection Pulse Interval set to [60] seconds.
```

O segundo excerto, resultado com a chamada ao `SENDJS` anteriormente descrito:

```
[INFO ][SERVER] [Thread 12172] Env [KVP4XK_PRD_COMP] DBAccess Connection Pulse Interval set to [60] seconds.

************************ (#####,####) ************************
[WARNING] RPO incomplete compilation. Some programs will not work.
Environment ... KVP4XK_PRD_COMP
RPO ........... \\IPA.IPB.IPC.IPD\kvp4xk_pr_prd_apo\outsourcing\clientes\kvp4xk_prd\apo_comp_erp\tttp110.rpo
Source List ... M460FIM.PRW 


[INFO ][SERVER] [21/11/2018 11:36:16] Starting Program U_SGEOJ001 Thread 12172 (####,#####)
*** Loading dbapi.dll
[21/11|11:36][WFPREPENV] Inicialização de ambiente
[21/11|11:36][WFPREPENV] Empresa: XX
[21/11|11:36][WFPREPENV] Filial: YYYYYY
[21/11|11:36][WFPREPENV] Função: WFPrepEnv
[XXXX] CONFIGURANDO AMBIENTE XX ZZZZZZ ------------
[XXXX] INICIO EXECUCAO JOB ENVIO XXXX 21/11/18 11:36:20 ------------
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo

POST /my/exemplo/end-point HTTP/1.1

Host: my.example.http.host:8080

HEADER_PVT: PVT_VALUE

Content-type: application/json

Content-Length: 190598



{"cliente":[{"cd_cliente":"MMMM","nm_cliente":"NOME NOME NOME","nm_fantasia":"NOME NOME NOME",...resto do payload
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: OK

POST /my/exemplo/end-point HTTP/1.1

Host: my.example.http.host:8080

HEADER_PVT: PVT_VALUE

Content-type: application/json

Content-Length: 190457



{"cliente":[{"cd_cliente":"LLLL","nm_cliente":"NOME NOME NOME","nm_fantasia":"NOME NOME NOME",...resto do payload
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: OK
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo

POST /my/exemplo/end-point HTTP/1.1

Host: my.example.http.host:8080

HEADER_PVT: PVT_VALUE

Content-type: application/json

Content-Length: 190424



{"cliente":[{"cd_cliente":"WWWW","nm_cliente":"NOME NOME NOME","nm_fantasia":"NOME NOME NOME",...resto do payload
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: OK
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: Resultado nulo

[INFO ][SERVER] [Thread 16304] [21/11/2018 11:40:16] Starting Monitor (####, #####)

[INFO ][SERVER] [Thread 16304] Env [KVP4XK_PRD_COMP] DBAccess Connection Pulse Interval set to [60] seconds.

POST /my/exemplo/end-point HTTP/1.1

Host: my.example.http.host:8080

HEADER_PVT: PVT_VALUE

Content-type: application/json

Content-Length: 190681



{"cliente":[{"cd_cliente":"KKKK","nm_cliente":"NOME NOME NOME","nm_fantasia":"NOME NOME NOME",...resto do payload
[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: OK

[INFO ][SERVER] Send TERMINATE (IMMEDIATE) to Thread (12172) User [####] Computer [#####] Server []

/*-------------------------------------------------------
THREAD ERROR ([12172], ####, #####)   21/11/2018   11:40:25
Connection terminated by the administrator. on ESCENVST(SGEOF001.PRW) 21/11/2018 11:28:55 line : 147

[build: 7.00.131227A-20180425]
[environment: KVP4XK_PRD_COMP]
[thread: 12172]
[dbthread: 16076]
[rpodb: Top]
[localfiles: CTREE]
[remark: |Emp :02/02020099 Logged :             SIGAFAT Obj :WFPrepEnv]
[stack: 31904 bytes]
[memory: 28475704 bytes]
[peak memory: 28469104 bytes]
[threadtype: RmtSockThread]
Called from LINHAJSON(SGEOF001.PRW) 21/11/2018 11:28:55 line : 147
Called from U_MAKEALLJSON(SGEOF001.PRW) 21/11/2018 11:28:55 line : 308
Called from U_ENVJSONAPLIC(SGEOF003.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45 line : 74
Called from U_EXECATU(SGEOF004.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45 line : 93
Called from U_SGEOJ001(SGEOJ001.PRW) 12/11/2018 11:06:43 line : 35


Variables in use
  ... diversas variáveis ...

STACK U_SGEOJ001(SGEOJ001.PRW) 12/11/2018 11:06:43

  Private 1: LPROCESS(L) :.F.
  Local 1: AAREA(A) :
  Local 2: CCODEMP(C) :02
  Local 3: CCODFIL(C) :02010001

STACK U_EXECATU(SGEOF004.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45

  Param 1: CEXEC(C) : J
  Private 1: BEXECROT(L) :.T.
  Local 1: CEXEC(C) :J
  Local 2: CRESULT(C) :
  Local 3: I(N) :1
  Local 4: CTABELA(C) :
  Local 5: ATABPRO(A) :
  Local 6: ATABGEO(A) :
  Local 7: NREGISTROS(N) :1
  Local 8: NCNT(N) :1
  Local 9: AREGISTROS(A) :
  Local 10: CMSGYN(C) :MSG MSG MSG pergunta?



Esta Operação não poderá ser cancelada.
  Local 11: CMSGEXEC(C) :
  Local 12: CMSGERRO(C) :
  Local 13: CMSGATU(C) :
  Local 14: CTIC(C) :11:36:20
  Local 15: CTAC(C) :
  Local 16: CELAPSED(C) :

STACK U_ENVJSONAPLIC(SGEOF003.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45

  Param 1: CTABELA(C) : SA1
  Param 2: COP(C) : T
  Param 3: CTABGEO(C) : CLIENTE                                           
  Local 1: CTABELA(C) :SA1
  Local 2: COP(C) :T
  Local 3: CTABGEO(C) :CLIENTE                                           
  Local 4: CHOST(C) :my.example.http.host:8080/my/exemplo/end-point
  Local 5: CPATH(C) :end-point
  Local 6: CEMPHOST(C) :exemplo
  Local 7: AHEADERSTR(A) :
  Local 8: CURL(C) :my.example.http.host:8080/my/exemplo/end-point
  Local 9: XPOSTPAR(C) :
  Local 10: NTIMEOUT(N) :240
  Local 11: CHEADERRET(C) :
  Local 12: CRESPONSE(C) :
  Local 13: ARESPONSE(A) :
  Local 14: CMSGHTTP(C) :[XXXX] Resposta HttpPost: 

STACK U_MAKEALLJSON(SGEOF001.PRW) 21/11/2018 11:28:55

  Param 1: CTABELA(C) : SA1
  Param 2: CTABGEO(C) : CLIENTE                                           
  Param 3: BTRATATIVAEVENTOS(B) : {|CJSONSTUFF|, SENDJS(CURL, CJSONSTUFF, NTIMEOUT, AHEADERSTR, ARESPONSE)}
  Private 1: _CALIAS(C) :TABSQL
  Private 2: _CTABELA(C) :SA1
  Private 3: CCHAVE(C) :        000001
  Local 1: CTABELA(C) :SA1
  Local 2: CTABGEO(C) :CLIENTE                                           
  Local 3: BTRATATIVAEVENTOS(B) :{|CJSONSTUFF|, SENDJS(CURL, CJSONSTUFF, NTIMEOUT, AHEADERSTR, ARESPONSE)}
  Local 4: CJSON(C) :{"cliente":[{"cd_cliente":"NNNN","nm_cliente":"NOME NOME NOME","nm_fantasia":"NOME NOME NOME",...resto do payload
  Local 5: NCNT(N) :232
  Local 6: NSIZE(N) :181259
  Local 7: CCODTAB(C) :
  Local 8: CTABPROTHEUS(C) :SA1
  Local 9: CTABXXXX(C) :CLIENTE                                           
  Local 10: CSTATUS(C) :A
  Local 11: CLINHA(C) :{"cliente":[{"cd_cliente":"PPPP","nm_cliente":"NOME NOME NOME","nm_fantasia":"NOME NOME NOME",...resto do payload
  Local 12: CSQL(C) :SELECT SQL SQL SQL
  Local 13: ACPO(A) :
  Local 14: CVALOR(C) :

STACK LINHAJSON(SGEOF001.PRW) 21/11/2018 11:28:55

  Param 1: CTABELA(C) : TABSQL
  Param 2: CCHAVE(C) :         000001
  Param 3: CVERIFICAEXCLUSAO(C) : (_cAlias)->DELETED == 'T'
  Local 1: CTABELA(C) :TABSQL
  Local 2: CCHAVE(C) :        000001
  Local 3: CVERIFICAEXCLUSAO(C) :(_cAlias)->DELETED == 'T'
  Local 4: CTIPO(C) :C
  Local 5: XRESULT(C) :ENDRECO RUA LOGRADOURO  
  Local 6: CJSON(C) :{"cliente":[{"cd_cliente":"OOOO","nm_cliente":"NOME NOME NOME","nm_fantasia":"NOME NOME NOME",...resto do payload

STACK ESCENVST(SGEOF001.PRW) 21/11/2018 11:28:55

  Param 1: CTEXT(C) : ENDERECO RUA LOGRADOURO
  Local 1: CTEXT(C) :ENDERECO RUA LOGRADOURO
  Local 2: CCLEAN(C) :
  Local 3: NLEN(N) :28
  Local 4: NFIM(U) :NIL
  Local 5: NDELTA(U) :NIL
  Local 6: I(N) :13
  Local 7: NIDX(N) :1
  Local 8: CCHAR(C) :R
  Local 9: NCHARASC(N) :65

Files
  ... diversas linhas...

 Stack : 
Connection terminated by the administrator. on ESCENVST(SGEOF001.PRW) 21/11/2018 11:28:55 line : 147

[build: 7.00.131227A-20180425]
[environment: KVP4XK_PRD_COMP]
[thread: 12172]
[dbthread: 16076]
[rpodb: Top]
[localfiles: CTREE]
[remark: |Emp :02/02020099 Logged :             SIGAFAT Obj :WFPrepEnv]
[stack: 31904 bytes]
[memory: 28475704 bytes]
[peak memory: 28469104 bytes]
[threadtype: RmtSockThread]
Called from LINHAJSON(SGEOF001.PRW) 21/11/2018 11:28:55 line : 147
Called from U_MAKEALLJSON(SGEOF001.PRW) 21/11/2018 11:28:55 line : 308
Called from U_ENVJSONAPLIC(SGEOF003.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45 line : 74
Called from U_EXECATU(SGEOF004.PRW) 19/11/2018 18:12:45 line : 93
Called from U_SGEOJ001(SGEOJ001.PRW) 12/11/2018 11:06:43 line : 35
-------------------------------------------------------*/

[INFO ][SERVER] [Thread 12172] [21/11/2018 11:40:25] Thread finished (####, #####, 27.15 MB.) 

[INFO ][SERVER] [Thread 16304] [21/11/2018 11:40:26] Monitor finished (####, #####)
```

Comment: Jefferson, você pode mostrar uma parte deste log, e confirmar em qual arquivo exatamente este log está sendo gerado ?

Comment: @siga0984, foram pegues em `console_kvp4xk_prd_comp_1101.log` e `console_kvp4xk_prd_comp_1101.bak` de um cliente. Vou tentar transcrever o máximo que tenho mantendo o sigilo e removendo excesso de conteúdo lixo

Comment: Eu conheço e uso a função HTTPPost() do AdvPL, que eu saiba ela é uma função básica da linguagem, e eu não conheço nenhum parâmetro ou configuração que faça ela se comportar assim.

Comment: @siga0984 vou continuar investigando. Só vi isso acontecendo em um cliente, não consegui reproduzir em outros. Pode ter algo a ver com a configuração do appserver, mas só testando. Quando conseguir algo a mais, informo aqui